# What happens when you conquer the whole map in Total War: Medieval 2?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

I would like to get some help about Total War: Americas Campaign.

I just finished a long campaign with New Spain in TW: Americas Campaign. Furthermore, I conquered all the regions and destroyed all but one faction (New France; they only have a few units and ships. I guess they didn't do well). When I finished conquering the last town, the victory screen appeared and I could only go back to the main menu.

I just want to ask if is there a possibility to continue playing (and destroying New France) or is that it?

Comment: OK, i didn't know that New France isn't playable, so i guess that was it and i finished game.

Comment: If you'd like, you could post your comment as an answer since you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

That particular win screen happens when you own all settlements. So yes, that's it; it is not possible to continue playing.

PS: A faction is destroyed if they run out of settlements, so technically, New France is already destroyed. If the game had continued, all their remaining armies/navies will convert to Rebels.